# Escaping Double Quotes in IMAP Search String

Tags: imap

I have a testing email with the following Subject:

```
this's is a "TEST" of "quote's"
```

I'm trying to find the correct string to give the IMAP SEARCH call so that it will find that email.  I am running into trouble because the syntax for a multi-word phrase is:

```
SEARCH SUBJECT "multi-word phrase"
```

However, the double-quote in the Subject string breaks that.

How should I escape the double-quotes in the sample subject so that the response is not empty?

My server is running Dovecot on CentOS 7, and my client is using PHP's imap calls.

Comment: Could you add what client/server software you are using for your search?

Comment: I'm running Dovecot on CentOS 7 for my main server (full setup is an iRedMail instance), with a PHP client making imap calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string Literal format (as opposed to Quoted format)

```
01 SEARCH SUBJECT {21}
<Wait for server to acknowledge>
this's is a "TEST" of "quote's"
```

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-4.3

> A literal is a sequence of zero or more octets (including CR and
> LF), prefix-quoted with an octet count in the form of an open    brace
> ("{"), the number of octets, close brace ("}"), and CRLF.    In the
> case of literals transmitted from server to client, the    CRLF is
> immediately followed by the octet data.  In the case of    literals
> transmitted from client to server, the client MUST wait    to receive
> a command continuation request (described later in    this document)
> before sending the octet data (and the remainder    of the command).

Answer (score 0):

When I talked to a Dovecot server from the command line, escaping the double quote with a backslash returned the right result for me: `S SEARCH SUBJECT "\""`.